# SPARQL Query for movies

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdfs

I am creating a web application that allows users to search for movies by using a SPARQL query.

At the moment I am using DBpedia to get the data.

The problem is I need to 3 pieces of data (title, genre, and release date). but the problem is I'm not receiving the genre of the movie but I am receiving music genre for some reason :/

Here is the query I have created

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?movieLink ?title ?genreLink ?genre ?releaseDate
WHERE {
    ?movieLink rdf:type db:Film;
               foaf:name ?title.
    OPTIONAL { ?movieLink prop:genre ?genreLink.
               ?genreLink rdfs:label ?genre.
               FILTER(lang(?genre) = 'en') }.
    OPTIONAL{ ?movieLink <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?releaseDate }.

    FILTER(lang(?title) = 'en')
    FILTER((?releaseDate >= '2010-01-01'^^xsd:date) && (?releaseDate < '2010-12-31'^^xsd:date))
}
ORDER BY DESC(?releaseDate)
LIMIT(100)
```

I have been stuck on this issues for a while so any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I have looked into using Linkedmdb but had a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia data primarily comes from Infoboxes on Wikipedia pages. For example, if you look at [the page for the film *Ayyanar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyanar_(film)), you'll notice that it contains two infoboxes:

- one for the film itself, with no mention of genre
- one for the film's soundtrack, with genre listed as Soundtrack

This is the reason why your query returns the genre of soundtrack for that film.

It seems [infoboxes about films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_film) do not contain any field for genre, so you won't be able to get that information that way.

On the other hand, the article is in the category *Action drama films* which is represented on DBpedia using `dct:subject`. I *think* you should be able to get the genre information from that using something like:

```
OPTIONAL { ?movieLink dct:subject ?genreLink.
           ?genreLink skos:broader+ dbc:Films_by_genre }
```

Though it wouldn't be very clean data (because Wikipedia's category structure is a mess). And it doesn't actually work for me, because such query exceeds memory limits on the public DBpadia SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing that up, by anychance would you know how to query linkedmdb for the same data

Comment: @IeuanWalker If you give us a LinkedMDB link and some query to start from, there's a better chance your second question will be answered

Answer (score 1):

@svick gives a good query. If dbpedia.org won't answer it, use our endpoint that includes transitive reasoning: http://factforge.net/sparql. Eg this works:

```
SELECT * {
  ?movieLink a dbo:Film; dct:subject ?genreLink.
  ?genreLink skos:broaderTransitive dbc:Films_by_genre
}
```

Comment: http://factforge.net/sparql even answers the slow version `skos:broader+` but in 180s instead of instantaneously. So please don't use that.